# How to count the number of messages?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

How to count how many messages each user wrote? Unique identificator - userId

From here I load json: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

```
result_one = requests.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
result_text_one_json = json.loads(result_one.text)
for item in result_text_one_json:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the job for [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(item['userId'] for item in items)
print(counter)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for item in result_text_one_json:
    d[item['userId']] += 1
```

At the end `d` will be dictionary with user_ids as it's keys and the count of each one's messages as its values.

Demo:

```
In [28]: from collections import defaultdict
    ...: 
    ...: d = defaultdict(int)
    ...: for item in result_text_one_json:
    ...:     d[item['userId']] += 1
    ...:     

In [29]: d
Out[29]: 
defaultdict(int,
            {1: 10,
             2: 10,
             3: 10,
             4: 10,
             5: 10,
             6: 10,
             7: 10,
             8: 10,
             9: 10,
             10: 10})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over each user and build up a dict with `userId` as key, and value as the count of items seen.

```
result_one = requests.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
result_text_one_json = json.loads(result_one.text)
d = {}
for item in result_text_one_json:
    if item['userId'] not in d:
        d[item['userId']] = 0
    d[item['userId']] += 1
```

---

EDIT: Although both answers have the same result, @Kasrâmvd's answer using [collections.defaultdict()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is a lot cleaner as you do not need to initialise each key with `0`.